# Bluemix Create App Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashboard, ibm-mobile-services

Getting the below error while creating app on Bluemix dashboard, irrespective of using unique App names

> BXNUI0005E: The 'MyFirstMobileAppTest' application could not be added.
>   See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to
>   check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for
>   information about getting help.

Comment: Can you provide the logs by entering `cf logs --recent`? Can you also post the full `cf push` command you are using with any additional properties and/or the manifest.yml?

Comment: We need more details to help you with your question:
- which application are your trying to create? Boilerplate or a simple runtime with its starting code?
- supposing you are creating the application from the Bluemix dashboard: could you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create a mobile application without any problems. This issue was most likely due a temporary outage.

If you experience this again, be sure check the [Bluemix status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) for any known issues and/or try again in a few minutes.